# Python, UnboundLocalError: local variable 'answer' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'answer' referenced before assignment

i cant figure out how to fix this problem. Im not very good at python but i want to learn,
i want it to be an 11 times table quiz on a loop.

```
    import time
    import sys
    i = str(input("Do you want to start the test: "))

    def test():
      global awnser
      x = str(input("What is your name: "))
      print ("Starting your Test " + x )
      time.sleep(1.6)
      eleven = 1
      while eleven > 12:
        eleven = eleven + 1
        score = 0
        answer = input("What is 11 x " + str(eleven ))
      if answer == (11 * eleven):
        print ("Correct!")
        score = 1
      else:
        print ("Wrong... HA")
        print (score)


     if i == "yes":
       test()
     else:
       time.sleep(1)
       print ("Sorry :(")
       sys.exit()
```

Comment: Minor nit:  [PEP 8 recommends](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) to "use 4 spaces per indentation level."  If you're going to write code that others are going to read, it's best to stick to the recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.  `global awnser` should be `global answer`.

A minimal working example of your code (on python2.x) looks like this:

```
def test():
  x = raw_input("What is your name: ")
  print ("Starting your Test " + x )
  eleven = 0
  while eleven < 12:
    eleven += 1
    score = 0
    answer = int(raw_input("What is 11 x " + str(eleven) + ' '))
    if answer == (11 * eleven):
      print ("Correct!")
      score += 1
    else:
      print ("Wrong... HA")
      print (score)
```